# Java Annotations processing for static analysis

Tags: java, intellij-idea, static-analysis, annotation-processing

I'm interesting in creating a tool which let you add an annotation to Java method and then it will show errors during compile time. For example, the variable is not in use or to know if the method has a return value.

(I know it is part of any basic IDE but I just want to take a project to learn some static analysis)

Can I achieve that with Annotations processing? Or should it be done with plugins development (for Intellij for example)? What is a good starting point for me?